# How to change default property of a custom Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The default property of my custom button is Text.I want to change to a custom property named MaximumClicks

```
Public Property MaximumClicks As Integer
    Get
        Return maxClick
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        maxClick = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the [`DefaultPropertyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultpropertyattribute.aspx) to your class:

```
<DefaultProperty("MaximumClicks")> _
Public Class CustomButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property MaximumClicks As Integer
        Get 
            ' etc
```

Comment: Wow thank you its work! very fast response i apreciate it